# Does this selector require the child to be a part of the named element first (i.e. hierarchical)?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following CSS:

```
#searchSection label, input, select
```

does that **only apply** if the `label`, `input`, and `select` element is inside the `#searchSection`?

**Something tells me** it's more like this CSS in the end:

```
#searchSection label { }
input { }
select { }
```

Comment: You could easily test this and see what happens.

Comment: @j08691, you're quite correct, I just like having community verification at times. I try to keep my questions very concise and targeted so they aren't long and drawn out but yet findable by a Google search if somebody else needs this help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,

This means

- Any `label` inside `#searchSection`
- Any `input`
- Any `select`

---

To apply to all `input`s, `label`s and `select`s inside `#searchSection`:

```
#searchSection label,
#searchSection input,
#searchSection select{
    color:#F00;
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way of writing the CSS so that I don't have to preface each with the `#searchSection`?

Comment: It seems like CSS requires excessive class proliferation -I could be wrong -but it seems I'm always creating a class. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud classes can be very powerful, especially for generalized situations, like adding rounded corners to certain areas.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is true.

If you want to select only the labels, inputs, and selects inside the ID then you need this:

```
#searchSection label,
#searchSection input,
#searchSection select {

}
```

If you want to apply similar styles to all three, then give each item a class property.  Let's assume you put `class="border-radius"`

Then write:

```
#searchSection .border-radius {
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```